# What matters more in the strength tester game at a carnival, momentum or force?

Tags: momentum, acceleration, velocity, collision

A buddy and I were arguing over which matters more in the strength tester game (assuming the same accuracy of the hit): 1) momentum or 2) force.

He was arguing that if you swing the hammer directly above your head you get more arc and thus more distance so the velocity will be greater at the point of impact and thus greater momentum.

I was arguing that force matters more and that if you maximize acceleration at the point of impact that you will get a better hit with the hammer.

Can someone explain the physics of this to me? Which matters more momentum or force?

Comment: force is change of momentum over time. Since the hammer comes to a stop (or even bounces backwards) you're effectively changing whatever momentum it has to at most zero when you strike the plate. Increasing momentum thus increases force and acceleration. So you were both right. More velocity helps maximize acceleration. So does allowing the hammer to bounce backward a bit

Comment: "More velocity helps maximize acceleration." I'm not sure what this means because acceleration is the change in velocity over time ... so if you are going at a constant 60mph you have zero acceleration and if you are going at a higher constant velocity of 100mph then acceleration is still zero.

Comment: When you strike the plate, the velocity goes from whatever you had before to zero (or even some negative value) and it does that in a short amount of time. If you give it more velocity to start with, the acceleration has to be greater to reduce that to zero when it strikes the plate. That or the hammer goes through the plate

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that the device "knows" when it is hit, is the force with which it gets hit, and the duration of that hit. Transfer of momentum $m\Delta v = F\Delta t$. So what matters is the momentum of the hammer's head - or more specifically, the momentum that you are able to transfer. Ultimately it comes down to giving the most momentum to the head of the hammer, and keeping it in touch with the impact plate for as long as possible (if the plate "bounces away you will not have transfered all the momentum - think golf club and golf ball). Also - if you let the hammer "drop" from higher up, you get a bit of help from gravity, so lifting it high will help a little bit.

Now if a high swing makes you weak (you are not able to accelerate the hammer's head because of the pose) you will end up with a slower hammer. But it's the total acceleration, and thus the impact velocity, that matters.

Comment: When using a hammer, you could say it's the acceleration that matters. But the jerk also makes a significant difference. If you get a really heavy guy to slowly step onto the plate, the puck will not gain much height at all even though you're applying a lot of force. You need a large force with a large jerk to ring the bell

Comment: @Jim - the transfer of impulse typically happens in a very short time, on the order of ms. A 10 kg mass traveling at 10 m/s has 100 Ns of momentum. If that is transferred in 2 ms the average force during that time is 50 kN - roughly the mass of an elephant, and a lot more than your "heavy guy". Ultimately you need to be able to impart velocity to the slider - and you can't do that when you move slowly. If the hammer is very light, it can move quickly but doesn't have the "punch" to create a lot of force. If it's too heavy you can't move it fast enough. As usual, the optimum lies in between...

Comment: That's true. My heavy guy wasn't heavy enough. But if you get an elephant to slowly step onto it, there won't be much of a rise either. This system is classically similar to a bellows. A slow increase in force applied doesn't work as well

Comment: In the above formula, does m = mass or momentum? Typically I've see p used for momentum but I want to make sure here.

Comment: @BrianTHannan $m$ stands for mass, and $m\Delta v$ is the change in momentum (mass is constant, velocity changes). The faster that change happens ($\Delta t$) the greater the force.

Comment: @Jim - I think we are in agreement: I did say "it's the impact velocity that matters". When you step slowly, the $\Delta t$ will be a large number, so $F$ will be small. Which means you will not go home with the giant teddy bear.

Comment: That's why I gave a +1 initially. But F will still be large with a large $m$, it just won't ring the bell because, like a bellows, the jerk/impulse has some significance

Comment: They are still not convinced. I guess the real argument is this: Is it better to swing the hammer straight above your head or to the side like you would chop wood with an axe?

Comment: In my experience the "chop wood" action works better - but there we are really talking about biomechanics, and my lack of abdominal muscles. It's really a question of velocity of the hammer at the moment of impact. If you can take a slo-mo video of your friend swinging the hammer you may be able to get resolution.